# Temporarily untrack files from git

Tags: git, expressionengine

I have a base install of ExpressionEngine (a CMS) which I clone for new projects.

The base install has hundreds of core files that will never change, unless I install an update of expressionengine. Tracking all these files makes git very slow.

So, I want to untrack all of them for during my development, and only track them when I install an update. What would be the best way to do this?

I have tried using .gitignore, but this isn't meant to ignore files that are already being tracked. Should I use exclude or assume-unchanged, or something else?

Comment: But why for? Tracked files which never change never get in the way (not shown by any Git command/tool unless explicitly told otherwise). So what's your real problem?

Comment: I don't think the number of files is the real reason of "git very slow".

Answer (score 2):

If your project use an external library, you may want to use `git submodule` to include it in your repository, then go in that directory to git checkout the tag (or branch, or sha1) you want to use.

```
git init newproject
cd newproject
git submodule add https://url-or-path/to/base/ee-repository target_dir
cd target_dir
git checkout sometag
cd -
git add target_dir
git commit
```